# Using useState to store state for an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with react and fetching data from here, https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. This returns an array of objects and I was hoping to store it in my useState hook. What I have tried right now is this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      email: "",
      website: "",
      phone: "",
      name: ""
    }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        json.map((object) => {
          setData((data) => [
            ...data,
            {
              id: object.id,
              email: object.email,
              website: object.website,
              phone: object.phone,
              name: object.name
            }
          ]);
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {data.map((info) => {
            <li key = {info.id}></li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

I feel I am making some mistakes while using the spread operator to store the data as a console.log reveals. When I place a console.log(info) in the data.map function, it keeps on repeating the ten objects. I am a little unsure exactly how that part of the code is working so if anyone can offer any suggestions or anything that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or
> string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for
> function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an
> object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more
> key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected. - [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

When you use `...` you copy everything thats on the right into a new variable. If it's used with an array `[...items]` it copies all the items in the array to an array variable named `items`. If it's an object `{...item}` it copies the fields of the object to a variable object named `item`.

In your code when you call `setData`, the `data` variable is the current/previous value of `data`, which is this:

```
[
    {
      id: "",
      email: "",
      website: "",
      phone: "",
      name: ""
    }
  ]
```

because of the initial default value that you set it as here:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      email: "",
      website: "",
      phone: "",
      name: ""
    }
  ]);
```

This means you're copying that array into a new array with a new object.

```
// for each json object
json.map((object) => {
         // update the data by: 
          setData((data) => [
            ...data, // copying the current data into this array
            { // and adding this new object
              id: object.id,
              email: object.email,
              website: object.website,
              phone: object.phone,
              name: object.name
            }
          ]);
        });
```

But this is calling `setData` inside of a `map` so each element of json will repeat the process above and that is not ideal. Instead it's better if you can call `setData` once. By mapping json to the fields you want and then merging or the other provided suggestions posted.

```
  // map to the fields we're interested in using
  const newData = json.map(object => ({
    //  only use these fields for newData
    id: object.id,
    email: object.email,
    website: object.website,
    phone: object.phone,
    name: object.name,
  }));

  // copy the existing previous data with the new data we just fetched
  setData(previousData => [...previousData, ...newData]);
```

This above is much nicer, if this were called multiple times there might be chance for duplicates, but since its in an effect without any dependencies it only gets called once on mount. If you're expecting this fetch to happen once and decide that you really don't need the initial default you set for data you can get away with removing the need for `...` spread/merging

```
  // we decided we didn't need the default obj
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // map to the fields we're interested in using
  const newData = json.map(object => ({
    //  only use these fields for newData
    id: object.id,
    email: object.email,
    website: object.website,
    phone: object.phone,
    name: object.name,
  }));
  setData(newData)
```

Theres also this other issue you have with the list rendering. You're not returning anything so it renders a list of `null` and that doesn't show anything so you need to make sure it returns something:

```
        <ul>
          {id}
          // this function returns undefined 
          {data.map((info) => {
            <li key={info.id}></li>;
          })}
          // this function returns
          {data.map((info) => {
            return <li key={info.id}></li>;
          })}
          // or return it with arrow implicitly           
          {data.map((info) => <li key={info.id}></li>)}
        </ul>
```

Comment: so in const newData example, basically we are mapping over the resultset which is an array of objects. And when we map it, it is automatically appended to newData one object at a time?

Comment: yea thats right, whatever you return is used to create a new array one object at a time

Answer (score 3):

remove `json.map` and place this code

```js
setData((data) => [
  ...data,
  ...json.map(({id, email, website, phone, name}) => ({
    id,
    email,
    website,
    phone,
    name
  })),
]);
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain in a little detail how the spread operator is used here?

Comment: By the way, the json contains additional fields such as address and username that i do not need so would that be handled with this?

Comment: @TanDev, sure! Because we know that json value is array of objects that also have same shape as our data(in state) we can spread it like normal array

Answer (score 1):

Initially declare `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` and wrap the return element `li` inside parentheses. See working code below,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        json.map((object) => {
          setData((data) => [
            ...data,
            {
              id: object.id,
              email: object.email,
              website: object.website,
              phone: object.phone,
              name: object.name
            }
          ]);
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {data.map((info) => (
            <li key = {info.id}>{info.id}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```